# Overriding operator multiple parameters

Tags: c++

I have been playing a little bit with C++ and found something that I could not explain myself.

Using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    int bar;
public:  
    Foo():bar(0){}
    Foo(int a):bar(a){}
    ~Foo(){}
    int getVal() const { return bar;}
};

bool operator < (const Foo& a, const Foo& b){
    std::cout << a.getVal() << " " <<  b.getVal() << std::endl;
    return a.getVal() < b.getVal();
}

int main() {
    Foo a(12);
    Foo b(15);

    if(NULL < (a,b) ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this as output ignoring completely parameter "a" but getting "b"

```
0 15
lesser
```

and if I change the condition to

```
a < b or operator<(a,b)
```

I will get (this is the desired behavior)

```
12 15
lesser
```

I think this might be some compiler stuff but I wanted to be sure

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve with the line `if(NULL < (a,b) )`?

Comment: This question points out a interesting behaviour. The downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: I was not planning on applying this on production code or anything just wonder why it does behave like that.

Comment: one lesson learned! use `nullptr`!!

Comment: The binary operator comes in between the two operands ; `a,b` means `operator,(a,b)`  with the result being an operand of `<`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ `NULL` [behaves like zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9897929/335858). When you do the comparison, C++ applies `Foo(int)` constructor on the left side, and [*comma operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) on the right side to arrive at the result that you see.

To prohibit the behavior when `NULL` is converted to `Foo` use [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) designator on your constructor (requires C++11 or above):

```
explicit Foo(int a):bar(a){}
```

Comment: Thanks, I always thought that comma was used as a separator but TIL it can be used as an operator as well.

Comment: I don't think there is any implicit conversion defined from `nullptr` to `int`, so the code might not even compile depending on the implementation's choice for `NULL`. I think the answer you link to is wrong since C++11

Comment: @MetalRiders Microsoft uses the coma operator with the `assert` macro : `#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )`

Comment: `explicit` constructors existed in c++98. see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2eaaf3a865bb619)

Comment: @M.M On Visual studio 2010, I'm using it, `NULL` is defined to 0. Even know `nullptr` is present in this version. Does `NULL` is defined to `nullptr` in later version ? That could breaks a lot of code!

Comment: @MetalRiders Every constructor with a single non-default parameter should be declared as [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), unless you need the behaviour of the implicit conversion, which should be rarely the case.

Comment: @nikau6 breaking bad code with a compilation error is a good idea IMO. Using NULL in some context that doesn't expect a pointer is already bad code

Comment: @M.M I agree. I have seen many code using NULL like : `int i = NULL`

Answer (score -3):

This code

```
 if(NULL < (a,b) ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

effectively converted into

```
 if(NULL < true ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

since in C++, any non zero value is true, so consider true as 1 then the code looks like

```
if(NULL < 1 ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

And at comparison NULL is equivalent to '0' then the code becomes

```
 if(0 < 1 ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

which is true.

If the function return `false`, the `if` condition will evaluate to false because `false' is zero in C++

```
 if(NULL < false ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

becomes

```
 if(0 < 0) ) /*  */
      std::cout << "lesser" << std::endl;
```

which evaluates to false.

Hope it clarifies

Comment: Can you explain this with your logic http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ANU2ksiFB3JpQYk9

Comment: `since in C++, any non zero value is true`. I don't think that is quite right here. Maybe in a dynamic language like python.  If it were true what is the type of `(a,b)`?

Comment: @DKG Your explanation would be right in this case if(NULL < (a < b) )